# LINQ-to-SQL: checking against a array of ints

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Am trying to write a query against a SQL database that will get certain members who have a roleID which matches the values stored in an int array.

If I want to check against a single value I can do this

```
from SU in SystemUsers
join WPM in Webpages_Memberships
on SU.ID equals WPM.UserId
join WPUR in Webpages_UsersInRoles
on WPM.UserId equals WPUR.UserId
where WPUR.RoleId == 5 // Want to check an array of values here
select SU.FirstName
```

but if I had an array of multiple values how would I check against those?

Thanks

Comment: We don't know what kind of LINQ query this is, but you may well find that `where array.Contains(WPUR.RoleId` would work. (I'd strongly advise you to use more meaningful names than "WPUR" etc, btw... but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Thank you this worked, I am checking against an SQL database, I will update the question, cheers for the pointer.